# MySQL query - 'CAST' ' CONCAT' - How to multiply several rows of data by a certain amount and display their individual totals in a new column in £'s?

Tags: mysql, sql

What's the best way to query a total price?

I want to multiply several rows of data by a certain amount and display their individual totals in a new column in £'s in my database?

What syntax do I need?

**Edit:**

I have loads of customers. Some have only one order, some multiple orders. I want to start charging them £1.50 per order, therefore, I need x(times) the order amount by £1.50 and display it in a new column in £. E.g customers with 4 order would need to be x £1.50 which would display £6.00 in column 3 and so on... 1.st column is name, second column is order amount. 3rd column needs to be total price. Hope that makes sense

**Update from comments:**
It's counted the orders, however it's returning `BLOB` values in the 3rd column where I want to display £ values for the * calculation of orders:

```
 SELECT   CONCAT_WS(" "
              , c.customer_title
              , c.customer_fname
              , c.customer_sname
           ) AS Customer
          , COUNT(O.order_name) AS Ordertotal
          , concat('£' * 1.5) TotalPrice 
 FROM   Order O, Friend F, Customer C, FriendOrder 
 WHERE C.customer_id = F.Customer_id 
 AND   F.Friend_id = FriendOrder.friend_id 
 AND   O.order_id = FriendOrder.order_id 
 GROUP BY Customer 
 ORDER BY C.customer_sname, C.customer_fname
```

Comment: What data are we talking about?  What column types?

Comment: I have loads of customers. Some have only one order, some multiple orders. I want to start charging them £1.50 per order, therefore, I need x(times) the order amount by £1.50 and display it in a new column in £. E.g customers with 4 order would need to be x £1.50 which would display £6.00 in column 3 and so on... 1.st column is name, second column is order amount. 3rd column needs to be total price. Hope that makes sense

Comment: @user1335184 - Welcome to stackoverflow. That's a good description of the goal. The only thing missing is your table structure (ie columns and data types) and possibly some sample data. You can update your question to add more details. The more accurate the details are, the more accurate the answers will be :)

Comment: Thanks @Leigh however, so far I have this, it's counted the orders, however it's returning 'BLOB' values in the 3rd column where I want to display £ values for the * calculation of orders: SELECT CONCAT_WS(" ", c.customer_title, c.customer_fname, c.customer_sname) AS Customer, COUNT(O.order_name) AS Ordertotal, concat('£' * 1.5) TotalPrice FROM Order O, Friend F, Customer C, FriendOrder WHERE C.customer_id = F.Customer_id AND F.Friend_id = FriendOrder.friend_id AND O.order_id = FriendOrder.order_id GROUP BY Customer ORDER BY C.customer_sname, C.customer_fname

Comment: @user1335184 - Is that the actual query? Because the `concat` statement seems to be missing some commas. Plus it is not calculating anything. Just stringing the pound symbol and "1.5" together. As far as the blob, the [mySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) say "if the arguments include any binary strings, the result is a binary string.". (Fyi, it is hard to read large blocks of sql in comments. So I moved it into your question for better readability. But you can always update your own question as well).

Comment: Is this your question too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422853/mysql-query-how-to-show-correct-values-not-blobs-by-doing-concat-and-creatin

Answer (score 0):

It is  a best practice to separate tasks, leaving computation to the SQL programming, and presentation to whatever programming language you use for the front end.

So your SQL should use it's native * operator. Your query might look like:

```
SELECT `column_1` * `column_2` as `product`;
```

this would return the product of two columns in a column named 'product'.

The £ sign is formatting. You should leave that to whatever architecture you have written for presenting the information. (PHP or java for example)

Comment: Thanks for your input. BUT... I want to do Sums, and start charging customers by multiplying their orders numbers by £1.50 each time, and display that total price in a 3rd column.... That's why I need to display a 3rd column to show this amount from my query...

Comment: Yes, pardon me, I started the post before your above comment.

Comment: Hope this is more helpful.  SELECT COUNT(*) * 1.5 as `total` FROM customers where `customer_number`='(some #)';

Answer (score 0):

Applying a lot of imagination because of the lack of description of your data and fields, this should do the trick:

```
select c.name, count(*) orderAmount, concat('£', count(*) * 1.5) totalPrice
from customers c
join orders o on c.customerId = o.customerId
group by c.customerId, c.name
```

Comment: Thanks @GRY however, so far I have this, it's counted the orders, however it's returning 'BLOB' values in the 3rd column where I want to display £ values for the * calculation of orders: SELECT CONCAT_WS(" ", c.customer_title, c.customer_fname, c.customer_sname) AS Customer,
COUNT(O.order_name) AS Ordertotal, concat('£' * 1.5) TotalPrice
FROM Order O, Friend F, Customer C, FriendOrder
WHERE C.customer_id = F.Customer_id
AND F.Friend_id = FriendOrder.friend_id
AND O.order_id = FriendOrder.order_id
GROUP BY Customer
ORDER BY C.customer_sname, C.customer_fname

Comment: @user1335184 As I wrote in the answer, don't use `concat('£' * 1.5)`. Use `concat('£', count(*) * 1.5)`.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't add the answer to the original question, since this makes finding out the question confusing.

It looks like everything was answered except the blob part -- here is the final result:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT_WS(
        " ",
        c.customer_title,
        c.customer_fname,
        c.customer_sname
    ) AS Customer,
    COUNT(*) AS Ordertotal,
    CONCAT('£', cast(count(*) * 1.5 as char)) AS TotalPrice 
FROM Order O
INNER JOIN FriendOrder fo
ON O.order_id = fo.order_id
INNER JOIN Friend F
ON fo.friend_id = F.Friend_id
INNER JOIN Customer C
ON F.Customer_id = C.customer_id
GROUP BY Customer 
ORDER BY C.customer_sname, C.customer_fname
```

To avoid the 'blobs', cast to char since you are creating a display string.  Here is the snippet from the query:

```
cast(count(*) * 1.5 as char)
```