# MYSQL Query - How to show correct values, not blobs, by doing CONCAT and creating new column with correct multipled total values?

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL query - 'CAST' ' CONCAT' - How to multiply several rows of data by a certain amount and display their individual totals in a new column in £'s?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404780/mysql-query-cast-concat-how-to-multiply-several-rows-of-data-by-a-certa)

here's my query, but I want to show values in £ in the total price column by multiplying the count by £1.50. Currently they are just showing 'BLOB' values, what am I doing wrong? I can't figure it out, any help greatly appreciated...

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(" ", c.customer_title, c.customer_fname, c.customer_sname) AS Customer,
COUNT(O.order_name) AS Ordertotal, concat('£' * 1.5) TotalPrice 
FROM Order O, Friend F, Customer C, FriendOrder 
WHERE C.customer_id = F.Customer_id 
AND F.Friend_id = FriendOrder.friend_id 
AND O.order_id = FriendOrder.order_id 
GROUP BY Customer 
ORDER BY C.customer_sname, C.customer_fname
```

Result: p.s I've left the customer names column out for confidentiality reasons

```
Name COUNT totalPrice
     4       BLOB
     2       BLOB
     1       BLOB
     3       BLOB
     3       BLOB
     3       BLOB
     1       BLOB
     1       BLOB
     2       BLOB
     3       BLOB
     2       BLOB
```

Comment: This has got to be homework - another user asked this [EXACT same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404780) yesterday!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you are multiplying a character with a decimal, which is non-sensical.
Do this instead:

```
concat('£', price_column * 1.5) TotalPrice
```

Note: change `price_column` to the name of the column with the amount you are totalling, or to `count(*)` to get 1.5 times the number of rows (not clear from your question exactly what you want)

Comment: Thanks @Bohemian, I have changed this to below, but I am still getting BLOB values. I have researched CAST, but not sure how to implement, perhaps this would help?! COUNT(O.order_name) AS Ordertotal, concat('£', O.order_name * 1.5) TotalPrice

Comment: Can you explain *in English* (not SQL) what you're trying to achieve? Because what it seems you're trying to do seems odd - it looks like you want the total price to be £1.50 per order, which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: In plain english. I have counted all the orders in column two. These are various totals for each customer. I want to display a 3rd column which shows the total price for each customers order total, by multiplying that order total by £1.50, regardless of how many orders. I also want to display a £ sign with the total value for each customer. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: at present in the 3rd column I am getting BLOBs. I know how to display the values in column 1 (names) and column 2 (order totals). I need to display a 3rd column with total price. Therefore column 2 needs to be multiplied by £1.50 to show in column 3...

Answer (score 0):

You are multiplying the string `'£'` by the number `1.5`.  I'm not entirely sure what that does, but it certainly doesn't achieve what you want.

Try instead:

```
CONCAT('£', COUNT(*) * 1.5)
```

Comment: Thanks @eegyal, I have changed this to below, but I am still getting BLOB values. I have researched CAST, but not sure how to implement, perhaps this would help?! COUNT(O.order_name) AS Ordertotal, concat('£', O.order_name * 1.5) TotalPrice

Comment: You can't multiple a string like "table" (which I presume is what `Order_name` is, given that it's a **name**) by a number.  That's meaningless.  You can only multiply numbers by other numbers.  Imagine you were doing it on  a calculator.

Comment: ok fair point, however it's an attribute, therefore I have counted the total orders of this attribute for each customer, and I need to multiply these total values by £1.50 and present them in a 3rd column....

Comment: That's what the proposed code above should do: multiply the number of items in each group by £1.50.  Can you show your revised query with using the above?

Comment: COSELECT CONCAT_WS(" ", c.customer_title, c.customer_fname, c.customer_sname) AS Customer,
COUNT(O.order_name) AS Ordertotal, CONCAT('£', COUNT(*) * 1.5)
FROM Order O, Friend F, Customer C, FriendOrder 
WHERE C.customer_id = F.Customer_id 
AND F.Friend_id = FriendOrder.friend_id 
AND O.order_id = FriendOrder.order_id 
GROUP BY Customer 
ORDER BY C.customer_sname, C.customer_fname

Comment: And that's giving `BLOB`-type output in the final column?

Comment: Yes, I think it requires a CAST function in the query, as this would display £ sign. However I haven't solved this yet.

Comment: Yes you probably need a cast. As mentioned in [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404780/mysql-query-cast-concat-how-to-multiply-several-rows-of-data-by-a-certa#comment13450463_10404780) the mySQL docs say "if the arguments include any binary strings, the result is a binary string.". I am not sure which part is being considered binary. But with only three parts it is easy enough to experiment.

Comment: @Leigh: Well spotted. My guess is that the connection is using the binary character set, so that's what `'£'` is treated as.  One could either explicitly declare it to be in a different character set `concat(utf8'£', count(*) * 1.5))`; explicitly convert the result `convert(concat('£', count(*) * 1.5) using utf8)`; or else first change the character set of the connection (which would be my recommendation) `set names 'utf8'`.

Comment: @eggyal - That makes sense and agreed the connection level setting is better.

Comment: @leigh Thanks a lot! I've switched back to a PC and all is working! Just to complete this query, I'd like to explicity use a CAST for the reasons stated. I'm unsure how to use the CAST in my query. This way it is giving me errors... CAST(CONCAT('£', COUNT(*) * 1.50) as TotalPrice

Comment: @user1371203: See my comment above - `convert` and `cast` are the same.

Comment: @eggyal Just to clear this up. I'm reading this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) as a reference I want to follow! When I put CAST(CONCAT.... it doesn't work, so how is this the same? It works with CONVERT, but I want to find the way of using a CAST as suggested in url...

Comment: CASTING after the fact probably will not help. Read eggyal's comments above for two ways to handle it.